# control video / audio with play/stop button

Tags: reveal.js

I am using reveal.js for a demo application in which I mix simple slides with slides with audio and slides with audio and video. In order to have this demo advance by its own, I use the setting as follows

```
 <script>
 Reveal.initialize({
   controls: false,
   progress: true,
   history: true,
   center: false,
   autoSlide: 3000,

  dependencies: []
```

});

the important parameter is autoSlide set to 3 sec. This generates a play/pause button to show up. Depending on my slides, I can also do control the timing with per-slide parameters set here to 14 seconds.

```
<section data-autoslide="14000" data-background="#4d7e65" >
    <h1>onto the admin view</h1>
    <video data-autoplay src="video/test2.mp4" width="100%" height="100%"></video>
</section>
```

my question: how can I make my video and/or audio files pause and play per this control. Currently when I hit the stop button, the slides will not advance anymore,but the video and audio continue to play. I have not seen anything in the documentation.

Maybe I miss something

many thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the `audio-slideshow` plugin that might do what you are looking for. With the plugin you can use the normal audio player controls for audio (and video). When the audio file is played completely the slideshow automatically advances with the next slide.

You can find a demo [here](http://courses.telematique.eu/audio-slideshow/)  and the plugin [here](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js/tree/audio-slideshow/plugin/audio-slideshow)

Asvin